# .asmx webservice with asp.net mvc 3 application and call webservice from phonegap android?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I am creating one android phonegap application, for that i need data from database through webservice that is in asp.net mvc3 application. i know how to call webservice from android phonegap but creating webservice in asp.net mvc3 stucks me.. hows that posible to create webservice in asp.net mvc3 and call from android phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest, fastest and probably the best way is http://www.servicestack.net/

you can have web service up and running in no time at all